# Yii2 Login failed to validate password

Tags: authentication, yii2

As the title says, i have a little bit of trouble in this area of the application. So basically, in my UserController i hash the password & in the login page it's verified with the standard security tool. Everything from the form to the user is good, but the check fails to return true. I don't have any interactions with the password in beforeSave/beforeValidate. Any ideas?

```
UserController: 
public function actionRegister()
{
    $model = new User(['scenario' => 'register']);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->password_usr = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password_usr);
        if ($model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'User created');
            return $this->redirect('/site/login');
        } else {
            die(print_r($model->getErrors()));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('register', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}

SiteController:
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            $model->login();
            return $this->goBack();
        }
        $model->password = '';
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

User model:
public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_usr);
    }
```

Login form is the default as the yii2 generates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the password field in the database, it was varchar(30) whilst generatePasswordHash returns a 60 char string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a problem

```
die(print_r($model->getErrors()));
```

login

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $this->layout = "login";

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        $model->password = '';
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

signup

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $this->layout = "login";
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: The register works fine (stuff inserted in db), everything is fine till the login password validation, so i don't think that line is the problem

Comment: remove $model->validate() in if condition.you need just username and password field. validate other fields not need 
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login())